# Link ActionLink in View to ActionResult in Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently learning ASP and I can't link an ActionLink in my View to an ActionResult in my Controller.
Here is my code :

ViewFiles.cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", "UploadController")
```

UploadController.cs

```
public ActionResult Download()
    {
        return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello world!');</script>");
    }
```

I'm just trying to return an alert for now to see if it works but I get a HTTP 404 error.

Comment: Your method is not called "Download", it's called "Telecharger".

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to translate the whole code to English before posting. In my code everything is called 'Telecharger' though so that is not the problem.

Comment: The last parameter "UploadController" is the route values and your action method  don't need any parameter

Comment: @mbadeveloper My VS help tells me the parameters are 'linkText, actionName, controllerName'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change *UploadController* to *Upload*: `@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", "Upload")`

Try this (**return JavaScript result on your ActionResult**):

```
public ActionResult Download(){ return JavaScript("alert('Hello world!');"); }
```

Comment: See my edited answer (Change UploadController to Upload).

Comment: Alright, now I get a new window with `alert('Hello world!');` written

Comment: @carlosfcmendes I actually used the return I my original post so I can actually get an alert window.